# Replace all under_scores in df names with space

Tags: r, stringr

A dataframe:

```
mydf <- data.frame(
  SOME_FIELD = 1:3,
  ANOTHER_FIELD = letters[1:3]
)
```

I would like to replace all underscores in the field names with a space. Tried:

```
mydf %>% rename_all(str_replace_all('_', ' '))
Error in fix_replacement(replacement) : 
  argument "replacement" is missing, with no default
```

How can I change all names to use spaces instead of underscores?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use -

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

mydf %>% rename_all(~str_replace_all(., '_', ' '))

#  SOME FIELD ANOTHER FIELD
#1          1             a
#2          2             b
#3          3             c
```

Since `rename_all` has been replaced with `rename_with` -

```
mydf %>% rename_with(~str_replace_all(., '_', ' '))
```

Or in base R -

```
names(mydf) <- gsub('_', ' ', names(mydf))
```

Answer (score 2):

We may use `sub` in `base R`

```
names(mydf) <- sub("_", " " , names(mydf))
mydf
  SOME FIELD ANOTHER FIELD
1          1             a
2          2             b
```

---

Or use `chartr`

```
library(dplyr)
mydf %>% 
   rename_with(~ chartr('_', " ", .), everything())
  SOME FIELD ANOTHER FIELD
1          1             a
2          2             b
3          3             c
```